# Compute $f^{(15)}(0)$ for $f(x)=(\sin(x^3))^3.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Compute $f^{(15)}(0)$ for $f(x)=\sin^3(x)x^3.$ Now ofcourse I can differentiate this 15 times and plug in $x=0$ however the purpose here is to use McLaurin expansions to efficiently solve the problem.

I know that

$$\sin(t)=t-\frac{t^3}{3!}+\frac{t^5}{5!}+O(t^7),$$

so

$$\sin(x^3)=x^3-\frac{x^9}{3!}+\frac{x^{15}}{5!}+O(x^{21}).$$

How should I think when I cube this? Obviously expanding something of the form $(a+b+c+d)^n$ is quite tedious. I know the first term is $x^9,$ but what about the rest?

$$(\sin{x^3})^3=x^9-...?$$

Butif I'm going to differentiate 15 times, don't I need the expansion of the 15:th order? I.e the $x^{15}$ term? I don't understand.

**EDIT:** Sorry, should be $(\sin(x^3))^3$.

Comment: You did all the work except the last easy step. The $15$th derivative is (essentially) the coefficient of $x^{15}$. (The $17$ is wrong but doesn't matter.)

Comment: double check your work so you don't transcribe wrong. is it $\sin(x^3)$ or $\sin(x)^3$?

Comment: Sorry, edited the question. Don't know if it makes any difference to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\left(\sin(x^3)\right )^3&=(x^3-\frac{x^9}{3!}+\frac{x^{15}}{5!}+O(x^{21}))^3 \\
 &= ( x^3-\frac{x^9}{3!})^3 +\text{o}(x^{15})\\
&=x^9 -3\cdot \frac{x^{15}}{3!}+\text{o}(x^{15})
\end{align}
We go from the first line to the second by noticing that everything that multiplies $x^{15}$ gives something $\text{o}(x^{15})$, and from the second line to the third by taking the first two terms of the cubic expansion.

Comment: Answers like this is what deserves a gold medal. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use
$$(\sin t)^3=\frac{3\sin t-\sin 3t}{4}$$
to get
$$(\sin t)^3=t^3-\frac{t^5}2+\cdots.$$
Then
$$(\sin x^3)^3=x^9-\frac{x^{15}}2+\cdots.$$
Then $f^{(15)}(0)$ is $15!$ times the $x^{15}$ coefficient here.

Comment: Ok, so let's say I'm in an exam, and I have no idea about that identity. How would I expand the cube?

Comment: @Parseval Once you have $\sin(x^3)$ as a Maclaurin series, you can calculate $(\sin(x^3))^2$ and $(\sin(x^3))^3$ by using the Cauchy product of two series.

Answer (score 0):

If you differentiate $15$ times then all powers of $x$ which are $<15$ will disappear and those which are $>15$ will still have an $x$ term which after setting $x=0$ will disappear. So yes, you need to differentiate the term which has power $15$ fifteen times

Comment: But there is no such term, as evident from my calculations.

Comment: Hence, the answer is 0 since the term has coefficient 0 as pointed out by @mathreadler

Comment: There is such a term but it's coefficient is 0.

Comment: Sorry, edited the question. Don't know if it makes any difference to your answer.

Comment: To my answer - no. It affects how do the series look, but the idea is this - look at the $15$th power and differentiate it $15$ times.

Comment: But how can I expand the cube? The above guy want's me to use an identity but I can't memorize them all for an exam.

Comment: To be honest, you can just bruteforce it (though the above solution is quite neat if you ask me). The thing is, you've found the coefficient in front of $x^9$ and as all your terms are multiples of $3$, the next one you can get is $x^{12}$ and the third - $x^{15}$. It shouldn't be too hard to find it but still, as @LordSharkTheUnknown pointed out - there are better ways